# Drupal website page load time over 40s, please help me

Tags: performance, drupal, pagespeed

I have been completed drupal (7.14) .website, but it load page very slow over 40 second.

The site name is: open casino bonus[.]com without space.

I had tried optimization this site such: install modules(boost, filecache, ...), optimization htaccess, gzip, using pagespeed tools, clear css and javascript,... etc but it not change.

I check error file log, it show: "Premature end of script headers: index.php"

Please check page speed test result this page: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120731_9E_H7W/1/details/

Load Time: 51.792s. 
IP: 182.50.148.1 
Location: Singapore 
Error/Status Code: 200 
Start Offset: 0.368 s
DNS Lookup: 50 ms 
Initial Connection: 318 ms 
Time to First Byte: 38969 ms 
Content Download: 856 ms 
Bytes In (downloaded): 12.3 KB 
Bytes Out (uploaded): 0.4 KB

Please help me,

Thanks a lot

John

============ Addition information ===========

Thanks for your reply,

I checked in php.ini, I think it ok, please see at: open casino bonus.com/phpinfo.php
I also check Performance Report in gtmetrix.com and I has seed the HTTP request and response very slow. For ex, the request and response at index.php over 15.71s, and over 1.5 second for each request (1 -> 2kb).

[Check Latest Performance Report](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/opencasinobonus.com/rrz90BIb)

I created the comparison for 2 server.

My Hosting: playtech.png - 2KB - request: 1.64 second
Other Hosting: playtech.png - 2.5KB - request: 46ms

Between 1.6s and 46ms,So I think have problems with my hosting. Do you think so? I using hosting 4GB Deluxe plant for godaddy.com, I'll contact with godaddy and let everybody know for help me :).

I'll try to check my problems.

Thanks all,

Best Regards!

John

Comment: This isn't the answer but I always remove dashboard and overlay from the modules on my D7 sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had tried optimization this site such: install modules(boost, filecache, ...)

You'll get slow page loads if you have too many modules installed. Disable AND uninstall all the modules you don't need.

> I had tried [...] optimization htaccess, gzip, using pagespeed tools, clear css and javascript,...

If you don't have avaiable CPU, disk space, or memory - these could actually slow things down.

---

***Site-specific issues affecting page load times:***

As [dorien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1496362/dorien) said, check your php_memory in your php.ini file. You can use phpinfo(); to see what your limits are and which php.ini file's being loaded.

The following site-specific areas affect page load times:

- The **PHP mode** your app is running in (mod_php, fast-cgi, cgi, etc.) Each has pros and cons based on your server resources and your website's module and theme dependencies.
- The **PHP memory** allocated to your site (More = faster. If you're giving your Drupal site less than 100MB, you're going to fail under load.)
- The **number, size, and dpi of the graphics** used in your themes/pages.
- The **number, size, and location of theme assets** used in your themes/pages.
- The loading of theme **embedded external resources** (css, img, js, etc.) from servers that themselves are slow or reside over high latency WAN connections.
- The number of **modules enabled**. (Less = better.)
- **Double compressing** your pages (e.g. Your server uses mod_deflate for page compression, but you're also doing it in Drupal.)
- Using **MyISAM instead of InnoDB tables** in your Drupal database.
- **Buggy custom themes, modules, or additions** to Drupal core. I know, I know... you're code's bug free.
- **APC cache** size and segmentation (If APC's being used, make sure it's cache size is big enough to avoid segmentation.)

---

***Server-specific issues affecting page load times:***

The following broader areas also affect page load times:

- Other **load on the server**. You're sure nothing else is slamming your server, right? Right?
- **Resource limits** (Is your VPS oversold? How's the RAID configured? If it's a dedicated server, how current/fast is the hardware?)
- Is your **server swapping for memory**? If so, MySQL crumbles. As your MySQL goes, so goes your site.
- Your **Apache thread, memory, and prefork** settings.
- **Improper MySQL config** settings. Check thread, innodb, table cache, and max users settings to start.
- The **load/latency of viewing computer/browser**. (No, really. I had someone ask why their site was loading slow when in fact that client was on a 128MB netbook tethered over a mobile phone's 2G Edge network.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll contact with godaddy for about server speed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have 40s on the server - that's your #1 bottleneck. Unfortunately without more information we wouldn't be able to tell you much more about what's going on there: slow database query, overloaded server, making live requests to another web-service to render a page.. Dig into your server-side logs, add some instrumentation.

Once you figure that out, you also have 10s of loading time on the front-end. You're fetching hundreds of images.. do you need them all? If yes, then think about spriting some of them to get faster downloads. You can also definitely benefit from sharding them across multiple domains / hostnames, to work around the connection host limit of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your php memory is exhausted. You can increase this in php.ini. Otherwise you might want to use the Devel module to check your memory usage.

Answer (score -1):

Well encountered the same problem with a drupal 7 hosted on my server and after hours of headbugging i took a look at the settings. php...
And there it was , the database server "host" was the domain itself (example.com) so it seems we had an lookUp overhead of 10sec.
After cursing and kicking the developer in the face i changed that to "localhost" or whatever your db host is and boom runs like hell!

hope to save someones time